# Linq: count by range

Tags: c#, linq

Please help me to create a linq query. I have a class

```
class Person
{
    string name;
    int age;
}
```

I need to group a list of Persons by age ranges (0 to 10, 10 to 20, ... 90 to 100) and count a number of persons for each range. Also I want to filter the list by name. For example, get a number of men called "John" for each age range.
Thanks.

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far please.

Comment: Where are you stuck?  The `.GroupBy()` extension method seems like it might be useful here.  Or even just a custom group class (`AgeGroup`?  `PersonGroup`?) and a loop to populate instances of that class.  There are probably lots of ways to do this.  What have you tried?

Comment: Thanks guys. I've finally found the solution. It's the same as ASh posted. Thanks to him too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

given

```
public class Person
{
    public string name;
    public int age;
}
```

you can get desired result using `Where` method for filtering and `GroupBy` + `Count` for grouping. Since all age groups are equls (10 years), `age/10` is a good grouping key.

```
List<Person> L = new List<Person>
{
    new Person{name = "John", age=30},
    new Person{name = "John", age=43},
    new Person{name = "Sam", age=42},
};

IEnumerable<Person> seq = L;

string nameFilter = "John";
if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(nameFilter))
    seq = seq.Where(p => p.name == nameFilter);

var counts = seq.GroupBy(p => p.age/10)
                .Select(gr => new { AgeGroup = String.Format("{0}-{1}", gr.Key*10, (gr.Key+1)*10), 
                                    Count = gr.Count()})
                .ToList();
```

output

```
{ AgeGroup = 30-40, Count = 1 }
{ AgeGroup = 40-50, Count = 1 }
```